# Plot data in different locations as a contour map

Tags: python, matplotlib, matlab-figure, heatmap, contour

I have data for many locations, I want to plot these data in different locations as a contour map or any different style. Here is an example of data I have:

```
    Date    Lat Lon Concentration
    1950    2   2   5

    Date    Lat Lon Concentration
    1950    2   2.25    7

    Date    Lat Lon Concentration
    1950    2   2.5 8
    .           
    .           
    .
```

I'd like to plot a heat map or contour map that shows each location's concentration.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `plot_google_maps` function from the MATLAB file exchange [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27627-zoharby-plot_google_map). This will create a plot with a worldmap as background zoomed in to the extend of your `Lat` and `Lon` coordinates. There, you can plot a scatter plot into with a colorbar.

```
% extract your latitude, longitude data from your input file (which I do not have)
% lat = <your latitude data>
% lon = <your longitude data>

% Your z-values for the heatmap (Concentration). I used random number here
concentration = rand(size(lat));

% Plot a scatter plot with a colorscaling on concentration
scatter(lat,lon,50,concentration,'o','filled')

% Add colorbar
colorbar

% Add google map section of your lat and lon data as background on the plot
plot_google_map
```

This gives something like that

[image]